# How to assign another object to point single object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NSString immutable allows to change its values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805442/nsstring-immutable-allows-to-change-its-values)

I want to point to an object where in, if I make changes to one object. the same change has to reflect to other object. How to do that?

I have done a sample, but it is not working.

Please check the code once. What is the mistake in my code?

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{ 
    str = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Taruni"];   
    str2=str;  
    str2=@"Kalpana chawla";  
    [self changeStr:str];  
    NSLog(@"str = %@",str);
    [str release];  
    [str release];   
    [super viewDidLoad];    
}  
-(void)changeStr:(NSString *)x  
{   
    x=@"Chandra";  
}
```

In .h file, I have declared in this way

```
@property(nonatomic,assign) NSString *str;
@property(nonatomic,assign) NSString *str2;
```

If I change the value of str2, str is not getting reflected.

How to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805442/nsstring-immutable-allows-to-change-its-values - look at this answer

Comment: and... btw... why do you release str twice?

Comment: I was also checking retain count values. Even after releasing twice, it is not throwing any exception. Amy I know why?

Comment: @DarkFighter.. Your link doesn't answer my question.. Even though I have changed it from NSString to NSMutableString, it is displaying th e same old value

Comment: did you change all the NSString to NSMutableString? including the param to your method? and the alloc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code,

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Taruni"];
    NSString **str2 = &str;
    *str2=@"Kalpana chawla";
    [self changeStr:&str];
    NSLog(@"str = %@",str);
    [str release];
    [str release];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
-(void)changeStr:(NSString **)x
{
    *x=@"Chandra";
}
```

Comment: In second line i got error - http://i.imgur.com/Ux1Rz.png

Comment: It was working on non ARC env.

Comment: Okay fine..... I think ARC doesn't allow direct assigning to a pointer type variable.

Comment: might be... I dont use arc.. I like doing all stuff myself

Comment: Great!  If you dont mind i will take your help when i need :-)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to change the content of a string you need NSMutableString.
Second of all, in your changeStr: method you did nothing but assigned the "x" pointer to point to another string (and x is local).. In method your pointer "x" is local and assignment (x = something) will not reflect outside of that method. If you want to change something outside you will have to use x.propertyName or [x methodName]. If you want to change your input as to what string does it point to, you need input as :(NSString **)x, then *x = @"Chandra" and [self changeStr:&str].
Third of all, you can not change constant strings (defined like this: @"constant string"), you will have to use [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", str] (rather yet NSMutableString for your purpose)